# List directories in a folder, ignore sub directories ANT

Tags: ant

Basically I have the following structure for a javadoc:

```
build
+---javadoc
+-------Module A
+-------Module B
+---Index.html
```

Module X are folders. I'm trying to list the folders there, ignoring subfolders, so I can create the main index. So far This is what I have:

```
<target name="x">
    <dirset id="dist.contents" dir="build/javadoc" excludes="build/javadoc/*/**"/>
    <property name="prop.dist.contents" refid="dist.contents"/>
    <echo>${prop.dist.contents}</echo>
</target>
```

But it gives me both the the Module's folder and all its subfolders. I know it should be a little detail but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change to use `includes` instead of `excludes`, and specify a wildcard that won't traverse sub-directories:

```
<dirset id="dist.contents" dir="build/javadoc" includes="*"/>
```

Further restrict the wildcard if needed:

```
<dirset id="dist.contents" dir="build/javadoc" includes="Module *"/>
```

Here's the docs on [directory-based tasks](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html).

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple. Thanks a lot, it did the trick!